# Paper specks/mockup design?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo

What I'm trying to achieve is here:

[image: The Volcano]

<sup>[The Volcano](http://dribbble.com/shots/987665) by [Yoga Perdana](http://dribbble.com/yoga)</sup>

Not the logo itself but the mockup that's used. The paper kind of look with the tiny white specs and scratches here and there. It looks spectacular, it really does. I've thought of so many ways on how to do this, and I just can't think of anything. I really like the design of it. Could someone tell me how to achieve this look? I see a lot of logo designers using it. So what's the secret?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Find a paper texture.
2. Put a b&w adjustment layer on it.
3. Perform a levels adjustment until its purely black or white.
4. Select black with the magic wand, and add a mask to it.

[image: Texture]

[image: Result]

You can open the mask (alt click) and fine tune it (add blur to soften the scrapes or sharpen etc.) to clean it up where necessary.

(Not quite as clean as the guy did it on dribbble.... but it's the general idea.)

If someone knows a better way.... ping me :)

Answer (score 1):

great example by user12985 but I would like to add that this would be better if done in Illustrator because it will give you the option to allow for die-cut decals if you ever wanted.  I typically try to design all logos in Ai for this very reason.

I asked a similar question to this, [Grunge effect for vinyl](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16075/grunge-effect-for-vinyl), awhile back when I was needing to create a logo that was to be sent to the cutter.